# Any way to speed up this sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have the following Postgres query, the query takes 10 to 50 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT m.match_id FROM match m
WHERE m.match_id NOT IN(SELECT ml.match_id FROM message_log ml)
AND m.account_id = ?
```

I have created an index on `match_id` and `account_id`

```
CREATE INDEX match_match_id_account_id_idx ON match USING btree
  (match_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
   account_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

But still the query takes a long time. What can I do to speed this up and make it efficient? My server load goes to 25 when I have a few of these queries executing.

Comment: Please consider instructions in the tag-info of the [postgresql-performance] tag I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT IN (SELECT ... )` can be considerably more expensive because it has to handle NULL separately. It can also be tricky when NULL values are involved. Typically `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` (or one of the other related techniques) is faster:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Applied to your query:

```
SELECT m.match_id
FROM   match m 
LEFT   JOIN message_log ml USING (match_id)
WHERE  ml.match_id IS NULL
AND    m.account_id = ?;
```

The best index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX match_match_id_account_id_idx ON match (account_id, match_id);
```

Or just on `(account_id)`, assuming that `match_id` is PK in both tables. You also already have the needed index on `message_log(match_id)`. Else create that, too.

Also `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` in your index definition indicates that your ID columns are [character types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html), which is typically ***inefficient***. Should typically better be [integer types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT).

My educated guess from the little you have shown so far: there are probably more issues.

Comment: What is the difference between your index and the one OP use with `USING btree`? or what make take that chooice?

Comment: @Juan: Btree is the default, `USING btree` is just noise, no difference. As is `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` for character types. The difference is the order of columns. The condition is on `account_id`, so it should be first: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684